# .htaccess redirect single specific URL with $_GET['id'] to new URL on same domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

For e.g. following is the URL to be redirected

`http://example.com/discussion/temp/?id=123`

Here value of `id` can be any integer. Also note that there is no such path/folders like `discussion` & `temp` on my domain (but for some reasons, until I make another update, I need to use this URL structure only). I want to redirect the above mentioned URL to following URL -

`http://example.com/new_folder/edit.php?id=123`

From some of the answers found on similar questions, I found out -

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=1
RewriteRule ^sub-dir/index\.php$ /path-to-new-location/? [L,R=301]
```

But, I am unable to use it in my case, as **I am unable to figure out how to redirect the `id` number which is actually a variable**?

Is something like following can be achieved (with dynamic `id`) -

`Redirect 301 /old-path/to-old-url    /new-path/to-new-url`

Answer (score 0):

You should look for [`RewriteCond` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), **RewriteCond backreferences.**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^discussion/temp/$ /new_folder/edit.php?id=%1 [L,R=301]
```

It tests if the query string has `id={numeric characters}`, and the request URI is `discussion/temp/`, if it does, then redirect to `/new_folder/edit.php?id={numeric characters}` permanently.